# How can install tensorflow in my hosting?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, pip, web-hosting

I want to install a Django application on my hosting. But I don't know why I can't install Tensorflow, a python library, from terminal. I installed other libraries with the pip install command. But tensorflow is not loading. Please help me. I am using tensorflow in my project. I don't know what operating system my host is using. But it's probably linux because if I enter wrong command the terminal gives message with 'bash'.

This is my hosting company :
https://www.cenuta.com/limitsiz-sinirsiz-hosting?gclid=Cj0KCQjwqc6aBhC4ARIsAN06NmOT68eQ3bxNf-cZBhrDdpT9QWB435r8YoCAdHZ5WwRHEVH-3zM_NLgaAnPiEALw_wcB

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.10.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (578.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╸ 578.1/578.1 MB 14.2 MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
((aiyguci/app:3.9)) [cankurte@cp64 aiyguci_app]$ # Verify install:
((aiyguci/app:3.9)) [cankurte@cp64 aiyguci_app]$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'


python manage.py makemigrations
(that is for run django project. i want to upload web server my project which using tensorflow)

None of PyTorch, TensorFlow >= 2.0, or Flax have been found. Models won't be available and only tokenizers, configuration and file/data utilities can be used.
No model was supplied, defaulted to distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad and revision 626af31 (https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad).
Using a pipeline without specifying a model name and revision in production is not recommended.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 443, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494,in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715,in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708,in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/opt/alt/python39/lib64/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/myapp/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path("core/",include("core.urls",)),
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/alt/python39/lib64/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/core/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .Main_AI import Algorithm
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/core/Main_AI.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .QuestinAnswering import Question_Answer
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/core/QuestinAnswering.py", line 7, in <module>
    nlp1 = pipeline("question-answering")
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py",line 711, in pipeline
    framework, model = infer_framework_load_model(
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 209, in infer_framework_load_model
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: At least one of TensorFlow 2.0 or PyTorch should be installed. To install TensorFlow 2.0, read the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ To install PyTorch, read the instructions at https://pytorch.org/.
((aiyguci/app:3.9)) [cankurte@cp64 aiyguci_app]$ python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Oct 11 2022, 18:16:34)
[GCC 9.2.1 20191120 (Red Hat 9.2.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
>>>
((aiyguci/app:3.9)) [cankurte@cp64 aiyguci_app]$ a
bash: a: command not found
((aiyguci/app:3.9)) [cankurte@cp64 aiyguci_app]$ python manage.py makemigrations
None of PyTorch, TensorFlow >= 2.0, or Flax have been found. Models won't be available and only tokenizers, configuration and file/data utilities can be used.
No model was supplied, defaulted to distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad and revision 626af31 (https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad).
Using a pipeline without specifying a model name and revision in production is not recommended.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 443, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494,in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715,in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708,in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/opt/alt/python39/lib64/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/myapp/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path("core/",include("core.urls",)),
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/alt/python39/lib64/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/core/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .Main_AI import Algorithm
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/core/Main_AI.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .QuestinAnswering import Question_Answer
  File "/home/cankurte/aiyguci_app/core/QuestinAnswering.py", line 7, in <module>
    nlp1 = pipeline("question-answering")
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py",line 711, in pipeline
    framework, model = infer_framework_load_model(
  File "/home/cankurte/virtualenv/aiyguci_app/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 209, in infer_framework_load_model
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: At least one of TensorFlow 2.0 or PyTorch should be installed. To install TensorFlow 2.0, read the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ To install PyTorch, read the instructions at https://pytorch.org/.
```

Comment: Pip did not finish installing correctly, look at the "Killed" at the end, this means you do not have enough RAM for the installation.

Comment: Dependent on your selected plan, you only have 1GB of RAM (in the most basic plan) which isn't sufficient for TensorFlow + models